# How to configure Ansible for Python virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ansible, virtualenv

I'm currently trying to run a playbook that uses a callback plugin.
This plugin uses a module called datadog:

```
import datadog
```

When I try to run the playbook, I get an error message:

> ImportError: No module named datadog

I order to work around this, I created a virtualenv, activated it and installed the datadog module:

```
virtualenv ansible -p python2.7
source ./ansible/bin/activate
pip install datadog
```

Then when I launch python and import the module, everything is fine:

```
python --version
```

> Python 2.7.15

```
import datadog
print datadog

<module 'datadog' from
'/Users/admin/code/venvs/ansible/lib/python2.7/site-packages/datadog/__init__.pyc'>
```

Therefore, I believe that the module is used properly.

However, when launching the ansible playbook, the error remains:

```
ansible-playbook -i ../../local/hosts.ini my_playbook.yml -e "ansible_python_interpreter=/Users/admin/code/venvs/ansible/bin/python" -vvv

ansible-playbook 2.6.3
  config file = /Users/admin/code/src/playbooks/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.6.3/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.15 (default, Jul 23 2018, 21:27:06) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)]
Using /Users/admin/code/src/playbooks/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed /Users/admin/code/src/local/hosts.ini inventory source with ini plugin
statically imported: /Users/admin/code/src/playbooks/roles/security/tasks/security-ubuntu.yml
statically imported: /Users/admin/code/src/playbooks/roles/mariadb/tasks/cluster.yml
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: No module named datadog
```

From what I can tell, Ansible is not taking the virtualenv into consideration. I would expect Ansible to use the path of the virtualenv in the `ansible python module location`.

How can I make ansible use the virtualenv? I didn't find anything related to the python path in the ansible documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/reference_appendices/config.html

Note: the issue occurs on the machine running Ansible. Not the machine being provisioned.

Comment: Why do you want to use a virtualenv? Just because import datatog does not work outside your virtualenv?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yes. I don't want to install datadog system-wide. Otherwise, I'll end up installing all versions of all libraries we are using. Leading to a version-nightmare

Comment: “*Ansible is not taking the virtualenv into consideration*” - why would it? You said you were running a callback plugin. `ansible_python_interpreter` specifies the interpreter for modules (which are uploaded to the target and executed in a separate process, even if the connection is local).

Comment: @techraf: from what I gathered from the (documentation)[https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback.html], the call back plugin is run on the controlling machine, not the controlled one. Furthermore, the error occured *before* ansible even opens an ssh connection to the controlled machine. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. Everything you quoted now is correct. Why then did you have an expectation of the opposite when you were writing the question?

Comment: @techraf: I'm expecting Ansible to add the path of my virtual env.'s modules to be added to "ansible python module location" in order to be able to pick up the module installed in the venv. Do you think I should tinker with `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH` or `ansible.cfg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems normal because `Ansible` does not refer to Python virtual environment in your case:

```
ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.6.3/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
```

In `virtualenv` non-installed packages are initialized from real system environment. So you can achieve it by setting up `Ansible` within `virtualenv`

Have a look at this example:

```
my_user@my_machine:~$ ansible --version
ansible 2.6.3
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

After installation of `Ansible` in `virtualenv`

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ pip install ansible==2.5.5
```

`Ansible` refers to the paths of Python virtual environment:

```
(py_venv) my_user@my_machine:~$ ansible --version
ansible 2.5.5
  ansible python module location = /home/my_user/py_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/my_user/py_venv/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

ps: Need to deactivate and activate again the `virtualenv` once to load the `Ansible` from virtual environment after the installation.

Comment: It actually doesn't change a thing. The installation went smoothly (`pip install ansible`).
When I get the version, the paths do not change:
```
ansible 2.6.3
  config file = /Users/jaep/code/cede/vagrant_boxes/ginkgo/src/edx-configuration/playbooks/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.6.3/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
```

Comment: Need to deactivate and activate the virtualenv once to see it is being reflected.

Comment: That was it. It may be nice to update your answer for other people.

Comment: Alternatively, adding the path to the modules to the `PYTHONPATH` did the trick.

Comment: @E.Jaep I clarified the answer.